# 403 error when accessing images via generate_signed_url function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to serve private images to users using the generate_signed_url function.

I implemented this and it worked at the first try, but after some time it has stopped working and I don't know why.

Now when I try to load the page I get a 403 error on all the images that are not public.

I made sure that the projects account had all the permissions for the bucket, but still I get a 403 error. Also, I can't see the content of the error, it looks empty to me (Maybe I'm not reading it right?) So I don't know the specific problem.

Here is my live test site: https://thawing-hamlet-36152.herokuapp.com/view_project/project/13

I added the snippet of code that generates the canvas and loads the image here. The last line is the call to generate_signed_url

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("{{'canvas'+(blob.name).replace('/','')}}");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image;

{% if detections[img_count[0]]|length > 0 %}
img.onload = drawImageScaled.bind(null,img,ctx,
 {{ detections[img_count[0]]["detection_boxes"][0][0] }} , 
 {{ detections[img_count[0]]["detection_boxes"][0][1] }} , 
 {{ detections[img_count[0]]["detection_boxes"][0][2] }} , 
 {{ detections[img_count[0]]["detection_boxes"][0][3] }} 
);

{% else %}
img.onload = drawImageScaled.bind(null,img,ctx, 0,0,0,0);

{% endif %}
img.src = "{{ blob.generate_signed_url(finish, method='GET') }}";
```

Comment: Can you write the code snippet how you are creating the [signed url](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program) and exact error message that you are receiving?

Comment: Hello Yurci, this is already on the snippet, in the last line: img.src = "{{ blob.generate_signed_url(finish, method='GET') }}";
blob is created from bucket.list_blobs(prefix=foldername)
I can't find the exact error message, I think I should receive an xml response stating the error, but all I can find is an empty response. I am looking in Chrome dev tools, maybe there is somewhere better to look?

Comment: Where are you running the code? From App Engine? Can you check Stackdriver logging from the console?

Comment: I am running my code from Heroku. I checked the Heroku logs but can't find anything there

Comment: Are you setting OAuth client ID and private key like explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program) step 3?

Comment: No, I am using the generate_signed_url function which does all of this automatically. It generates an URL that looks like the one specified in the documentation. Could be that there was something wrong in the signature though

Comment: In which part of your code are you authenticating your self with GCP? 403 error codes implies you have problem with [IAM permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions). You are using a service account, right? Can you control that service account has Cloud Storage Role like explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program#signing-language) on the section how to generate a private key.

Comment: Yes, it is not shown in the code but I am using a Google service account. Actually, the same application is creating the Storage folder and uploading the images, so it has to be correctly authenticated.

Comment: I was able to view the entire error response using Firefox (Chrome just showed an empty response, weird). Here is the full XML response
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied.</Message><Details>Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to BUCKET_NAME/FILE_NAME</Details></Error>

Answer (score 0):

Took me way too long but I found the solution.

The img.src = "{{ blob.generate_signed_url(finish, method='GET') }}"; method was inside a Jinja template.
When Jinja read the string, it translated the "&" in the URL to "&amp" to make it compliant with UTF8.
This made the arguments not get read by Google, and the request was interpreted as an anonymous request.

The solution was removing the "amp" from the URLs which you can do by using the Jinja |safe filter